# How to access QQmlListProperty<T> size function from Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

When you implement a QQmlListProperty and defined the count and at functions you can then call this from the Qml side. For the at function I have already understand that I can use the following sintax:

```
collection.items[0]
```

However, I couldn't still understand how do I call the size/length/count function. Does any know?

Answer (score 3):

I have just found the answer:

```
collection.length
```

[EDIT]

The answer is in Qt Documentation:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html

Comment: A link to where you found that would be useful for others.

Comment: @Mitch [When integrating with C++, note that any QQmlListProperty value passed into QML from C++ is automatically converted into a list value, and vice-versa](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-list.html) Hope link will help a bit :p

Comment: Thanks @nib. :) OP might want to edit that into their answer.